# Trying to connect oracle db from python using cx_oracle and found "ppcx_Oracle.i386 : Python interface to Oracle" using yum list installed

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

When tried to import cx_Oracle getting error module not found. 
Not sure what exactly "ppcx_Oracle.i386" is for and the way to utilize it.

=================================================================== Matched: ppcx_Oracle ====================================================================
ppcx_Oracle.i386 : Python interface to Oracle

is "ppcx_Oracle.i386" anything related to "cx_Oracle" package or i have to look for other options to install cx_Oracle to connect oracle database?

Environment : RHEL 5.4 and python 2.4,2.6

PS: Not having any issues in cx_Oracle since i have already used it in one of my servers.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should have Oracle Instant Client installed on the machine (or Oracle DB). The cx_oracle will use its shared libraries.

Then run this command to install cx_oracle itself:

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```

More on how to configure it and a code examples can be found here.

https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

ppcx_oracle.i386 looks like some non-official interface, I don't know it and could not give any recommendations about it.